# Join Column and sort

Tags: mysql

i cant make it, this is the real situation i want to build

```
SELECT vertical.ext, vertical.pengguna, vertical.nostaf, vertical.pengguna2, vertical.nostaf2, vertical.pengguna3, vertical.nostaf3, cil_personal.*
FROM cil_personal
JOIN vertical ON (vertical.ext = cil_personal.ext)
WHERE cil_personal.year = 2014 AND cil_personal.month = 06  
ORDER BY nostaf,nostaf2,nostaf3 ASC
```

i got result like this

```
column column column column column column  nostaf  nostaf2 nostaf3
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     10 
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     11  
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt             213
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt                     45
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     30   
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     55 

it should be

column column column column column column  nostaf  nostaf2 nostaf3
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     10 
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     11  
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     30        
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt             45          
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     55        
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt                      213



or

column column column column column column allstaf
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     10 
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     11  
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     30       
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     45              
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     55   
  txt    txt    txt    txt    txt    txt     213
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.* FROM table1 T1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS T2 ON T1.id1 = T2.allid GROUP BY T2.allid;
```

You can use different kind of join as per your use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the data-structure of the table, but the below query should do it. However you may get a blank row so to eliminate that you will need to add a condition in the query as
`where allname <> ''`  if you add some '' for that names field or if its NULL then use
`where allname is not null` and you can also change `union` to `union all` which is better.

```
select allname,allid
from
( 
  select name1 as allname, id1 as allid from your_table
  union
  select name2 as allname, id2 as allid from your_table
  union 
  select name3 as allname, id3 as allid from your_table
)x
order by allid
```

Comment: tq for reply, i cant get it, i edit the real question

Comment: This appears to be a different question that what you asked earlier. However post the table structure along with the data and the expected result.